# How to apply regex to entire file, not just line after line?

Tags: java, regex

I want to apply my regular expression not just to the first line of the text file, but to the all lines together. 
Currently it matches only when the entire appropriate match is on one line. And if the appropriate match continues on the next line - it doesn't match at all.

```
 class Parser {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(include|"
            + "integrate|"
            + "driven based on|"
            + "facilitate through|"
            + "contain|"
            + "using|"
            + "equipped"
            + "integrate|"
            + "implement|"
            + "utilized to facilitate|"
            + "comprise){1}"
            + "[\\s\\w\\,\\(\\)\\;\\:]*\\.");  //Regex
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:/test/test.txt")); // read the file


    String line;
    PrintWriter pWriter = null; 
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {           
      Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(line);  
     while (matcher.find()) { 

         try{
             pWriter = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("E:/test/test1.txt", true)));//append any given input 
             pWriter.println(matcher.group());  //write the result of matcher to the new file
         } catch (IOException ioe) { 
             ioe.printStackTrace(); 
         } finally { 
             if (pWriter != null){ 
                 pWriter.flush(); 

                 pWriter.close(); 
             } 
         }

        System.out.println(matcher.group());   

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide test data? Do you have new lines in between the expressions that you are trying to match?

Comment: @Razib: There is no "global modifier" in Java, it doesn't need one.  But even in languages that do use it (like JavaScript or Perl), it wouldn't be relevant to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `while ((line = r.readLine()) != null)` to this:

```
String file = ""; // Basically, a conglomerate of all of the lines in the file
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    file += line; // Append each line to the "file" string
}
Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(file);
while (matcher.find()) {
    /* Blah blah blah, your outputting goes here. */
}
```

The reason why this happens is because you're doing each line individually. For what you want, you need to apply the regex to the file *all at once*.

Comment: No problem, happy to help! :) If this solved your question, I'd suggest that you mark it as the answer so others can quickly see this as well.

Comment: it's a little bit strange with a test data for this regex. When  I use my own text that I typed in -the regex finds everything that I need. But when I'm using the text from the converted PDF File to txt- regex finds only the first match. I think it reads only limited amount of characters

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko  Well I told you that at least three times before he gave his answer... (2 of the comments I had removed). Always the same...

Comment: @maraca: Your answer removes any **line breaks** (`\n`) in the String, which aren't present due to the  functionality of `readLine()`. With your example, "com\nprise," two calls of `readLine()` would return "com" and "prise," but OP wants "comprise," which is found if you add all of the strings together in my answer.

Comment: @kkirigaya read the first line of my answer. Which was there in similar form long before you answered. So no, my answer won't first match "com" and then "prise", it will match the whole file.

Comment: @maraca   thank you very much for your solutions . maybe you have an idea why it happens so: it's a little bit strange with a test data for this regex. When I use my own text that I typed in -the regex finds everything that I need. But when I'm using the text from the converted PDF File to txt- regex finds only the first match. I think it reads only limited amount of characters. maybe it depends on text encoding?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the matcher is applied per line, it needs to be applied to the whole file to work as intended.

Regex are greedy, you will match the whole String on the first match unless you have `.` (or other special characters) in your String:

```
...
        + "comprise){1}"
        + "[\\s\\w\\,\\(\\)\\;\\:]*\\.");  //Regex
```

On the last line you match any whitespace and word, so pretty much anything but `.`. Also the `{1}` and most of the `\` are superfluous (because in `[]`):

```
...
        + "comprise)"
        + "[\\s\\w,();:]*\\.");  //Regex
```

If you don't care about the newline characters just remove them first and it should work (I see no way around it if you have something like `"com\nprise"` and want to match that):

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\n+", "");
```

Comment: and on what position in code should I insert s = s.replaceAll("\\n+", "");   ?

Comment: after you read the data, you need to read the whole file and then replace in the resulting string, then apply the matcher. Because you've gotten rid of all new lines, you may want to add a \n after each match in the output file

Comment: @OlegNekhayenko nevermind the comment about \n, you use PrintWriter it's done automatically... the rest is correct.